# How can I use characters like ╔ ═ and ╗ as part of strings in Dev C++?

Tags: c, string, char

I just don't know how. I have to put them in a variable first like:
    char c1=201;
Is there any way I can put the characters directly onto a string?
Charcters like: ╔ ═ and ╗

Comment: What did you try? Something like `char *strangestring = "╔ ═ aaa ╗";` or what else?

Comment: It's all a matter of displaying using the correct codepage (such as ["MS-DOS" CP 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)) if using "8 bit ANSI" characters written to a terminal - or using a compatible viewer (with supported font), such a text editor, if using Unicode.

Comment: I added the [tag:c] tag.

Comment: Now that the others have answered your question, one piece of advice: Do not use Dev-C++. It's extremely outdated and, at times, actively worse than plain text editors.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis That depends. The old pre-5 versions are indeed quite crap, but this version, http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/, is quite usable, not outdated, and comes with up to date (x64) compilers. It's even portable!

Comment: @Orwell I wasn't aware of your project. Congratulations, it's good that you've picked it up! My comment was really targeted to people who've found out about Dev-C++ from a beginner book (which usually means they've found the outdated version). I believe that if someone is aware of your version, it means that they actually know what they're doing so they know enough to ignore my previous comment anyway. =)

Answer (score 4):

You can enter arbitrary bytes into a string with the octal escapes.

```
char *s = "\311";  //== Decimal 201
```

On Windows, you can also use the `charmap` application. But you'll have to pick a font that has the characters in order to select them from the grid.

Answer (score 1):

The old way to do this is to hold the `Alt` key down and type the code on the numeric keypad.  This still works, but is confusing depending on what codepage you are using.  Have a go anyway...

If I type `Alt-201` (on the keypad, not the number strip), I get this: ╔

This might be a windows-only thing, by the way.  Not completely sure =)

Comment: I can't do something like:
     string symbols = "╔ ═ aaa ╗";

because Alt-201 doesn't give out '╔'. Instead, it gives out '+'.

I can't copy and paste the character either.